# Attach webhook to Quire task

Tags: quire-api

An example to attach a webhook to a project is given in https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/35

Could you please also give an example to add a webhook to a task (instead of a project) ? I tried the following:

```
request({
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    url: urlAPI + "/task/id" + "/" + projectID + "/" + newTask.id,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        addFollowers: ["app"]
    })
});
```

but I systematically receive a 403 (forbidden) error.

Do you have any idea why this would not work ?

2nd question : can you immediately attach a webhook when creating a task, or do you need to do it in two steps (first create the task, then update it) ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

PS: found a solution as suggested in https://github.com/quire-api/quire-api/issues/30 :

> what helped is to revoke the permissions from your user account.
> Login to quire as a normal user, click the profile Icon -> My Apps and then revoke the permission for your current app.

and then grant the permission again, now response status is 200